# Looking for stats on relation between rep, number of questions, and number of questions downvoted is

Tags: feature-request, reputation, asking-questions, statistics

I'm looking for some following stats:

> A detailed histogram depicting for a given amount of rep, what the average number of questions asked is

> Conversely, a detailed histogram depicting for a given number of questions asked, what the average rep of such a user it

> A detailed histogram depicting for a given number of questions asked, what the average number of questions on which they've cast a downvote is

Forgive me if some of these have already been asked. I tried searching for duplicates.

No clue how to find this on the site, I'm sure a way exists. btw, no clue what to tag this.

Comment: Somebody good with SQL could probably get this from a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/queries) query, then plot the data in another program. It would be a pretty complex task, though, particularly if you're looking for a histogram on 3 variables (I assume as an animation of 2D histograms?).

Comment: It might make the task easier if you just state directly whatever hypothesis you're looking to support (e.g. you suspect that higher rep users downvote more, or ask fewer questions, etc).

Comment: @AlexanderGruber yeah basically, but I want to look at the data first. I'll try to get around to clarifying this more if I can too.